# How to perform validations in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

| CPU | GPU | FPGA | VPU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Option1 | cbutton1 | cbutton2 | cbutton3 |
| Option2 | n/a | xbutton1 | xbutton2 |
| Option3 | abutton1 | n/a | n/a |

I am new to cypress and I have some hardware validations that I need to write cypress tests. Here are some scenarios that I am looking to write tests for:

Scenario 1: If option1 from CPU is selected then option2 and option3 get disabled , I can only select cbutton1 or cbutton2 or cbutton3. After selecting cbutton1 or cbutton2 or cbutton3 the other buttons get disabled.

Scenario 2: If option2 from cpu is selected then option1 and option3 get disabled, I can only select xbutton1 or xbutton2. After selecting xbutton1 or xbutton2 the other button get disabled.

Scenario 3: If option3 from CPU is selected then option1 and option2 get disabled, I can only select abutton1.

```html
<div class="select-row" data-cy-id="config1Row">
  <div class="colA">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="colB">
    <div class="configRow">
      <div class="sc-fzoLsD hQunTL hardwareTypeContainer">
        <div class="hardwareTypeName">
          <div class="col1">
            <h3>CPU</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>CPU description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col3">
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hardwareCardRow">
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="card" data-cy-id="option1">
              <div class="title">i7</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>i7 description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="card" data-cy-id="option2">
              <div class="title">Xeon</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>xdescription!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="card" data-cy-id="option3">
              <div class="title">Atom</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>atom description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sc-fzoLsD hQunTL hardwareTypeContainer">
        <div class="hardwareTypeName">
          <div class="col1">
            <h3>GPU</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>GPU description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col3">
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hardwareCardRow">
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="disabled card" data-cy-id="cbutton1">
              <div class="title">Graphics</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>iris description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sc-fzoLsD hQunTL hardwareTypeContainer">
        <div class="hardwareTypeName">
          <div class="col1">
            <h3>FPGA</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>FPGA description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col3">
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hardwareCardRow">
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="disabled card" data-cy-id="button2">
              <div class="title">I10</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>Adescription!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sc-fzoLsD hQunTL hardwareTypeContainer">
        <div class="hardwareTypeName">
          <div class="col1">
            <h3>VPU</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>VPU description!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col3">
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hardwareCardRow">
          <div class="sc-fzozJi cPPA-df padding">
            <div class="disabled card" data-cy-id="xbutton3">
              <div class="title">VPU</div>
              <img src="/images/icons/chip.png" alt="chip" class=".chip" />
            </div>
            <div class="sc-AxmLO fiWSWR">
              <div class="arrow_box_container show">
                <img
                  src="/images/icons/info.svg"
                  class="info"
                  alt="more info icon"
                />
                <div class="hide arrow_box">
                  <img
                    class="close"
                    src="/images/icons/chevron-small-down.svg"
                    alt="close icon"
                  />
                  <p>Mdescription!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these data in a table? Can you share the HTML DOM for this?

Comment: Hi, @AlapanDas modified OP with DOM

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you an answer with the info supplied. What does 'selected' look like? Is it an attribute, are the elements not selected disabled?

Comment: Hi @Ackroydd, Yes the elements not selected will be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to set up the data so that each scenario is present in the table for different tests (one test per scenario).
Then it's just a simple matter of asserting the disabled class, for example

**Scenario 1**

```
cy.contains('cbutton1').should('not.have.class', 'disabled')    
cy.contains('xbutton1').should('have.class', 'disabled')
...  // etc
```

I'm assuming that the presence of the disabled class is the key thing to test, seems logical.

You can also do this in a data-driven way if there's a lot of scenarios to handle.

---

I'm not sure the `cy.contains('xbutton1')` gets you where you need to go.

In your DOM, the first disabled element has `<p>iris description!</p>`. If this is the element that would show up in the table cell, then

```
cy.contains('iris description!').should('have.class', 'disabled')
```

would not work. You may have to navigate to the parent, like this

```
cy.contains('p', 'iris description!')   // more specific, grabs the <p>
  .parents('[class="hardwareCardRow"]') // get the parent row
  .find('[data-cy-id="cbutton1"]')      // go cell that should be disabled
  .should('have.class', 'disabled')     // assert it is disabled
```

---

Data-driven tests might look something like this

```
const scenarios = [
  { option: 'Option1', cellText: 'iris description!', disabledItem: 'cbutton1' },
  { option: 'Option2', cellText: 'lily description!', disabledItem: 'cbutton2' },
  // etc
}

scenarios.forEach(data => {
  
  it(`should be disabled, testing ${data.option}`, () => {  // back-ticks on description
                                                            // for template literal
    cy.contains('p', data.cellText)
      .parents('[class="hardwareCardRow"]') 
      .find(`[data-cy-id="${data.disabledItem}"]`) // back-ticks on the selector
      .should('have.class', 'disabled')    

  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! the last solution traversing through the parent worked for me. But I do have more scenarios to test and how should I perform it in a data-driven way.

Comment: Data-driven tests just extract the parts that change each scenario into an array data structure and repeats the commands for each one. I'll give an example.